# Segmentation Fault in hsearch

Tags: c, linux, hash, segmentation-fault

I am using  (http://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch) in my source code. I wrote a very basic code to test the hash functionality (did not want to reinvent the wheel by writing my own hash implementation). I see that it crashes with a segmentation fault in the search routine.

Any idea why its crashing?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <search.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


 char *data[] = {
 "cpe1","cpe2","cpe3","cpe4","cpe5","cpe6","cpe7","cpe8","cpe9","cpe10","cpe11","cpe12","cpe13"};

int main()
{
ENTRY ep, ep1, *ep_ptr, ep2;
int loop;
char *ptr;
char input[100];

hcreate (30);

for (loop=0; loop<13;loop++)
{
    ptr = malloc (100);
    sprintf (ptr, "%d.%d.%d.%d%c", loop+1, loop*2, loop*3, loop, '\0');

    ep.key = data[loop];
    ep.data = (void *) ptr;

    printf ("%s --> %s\n", ep.key, (char *) ep.data);

    ep_ptr = hsearch(ep, ENTER);
}

ep2.data = (void *) "cpe1";
ep_ptr = hsearch(ep2, FIND);

printf("%9.9s -> %9.9s: %s\n", ep2.key,
       ep_ptr ? ep_ptr->key : "NULL", ep_ptr ? (char *)(ep_ptr->data) : "NULL");

return 0; 
}
```

OUtput:

```
 (gdb) r
 Starting program: /home/globus/code/cpe/a.out 
 warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
 cpe1 --> 1.0.0.0
 cpe2 --> 2.2.3.1
 cpe3 --> 3.4.6.2
 cpe4 --> 4.6.9.3
 cpe5 --> 5.8.12.4
 cpe6 --> 6.10.15.5
 cpe7 --> 7.12.18.6
 cpe8 --> 8.14.21.7
 cpe9 --> 9.16.24.8
  cpe10 --> 10.18.27.9
 cpe11 --> 11.20.30.10
 cpe12 --> 12.22.33.11
 cpe13 --> 13.24.36.12

  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  __strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:32
  32    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S: No such file or directory.
 (gdb) bt
 #0  __strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:32
 #1  0x00007ffff7b0ba71 in __GI_hsearch_r (item=..., action=FIND, retval=0x7fffffffdfd8, 
     htab=0x7ffff7dd67d0) at hsearch_r.c:149
 #2  0x00007ffff7b0b92e in hsearch (item=..., action=<optimized out>)
  at hsearch.c:34
 #3  0x00000000004007a0 in main () at hash_test.c:32
 (gdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching you should set `ep2.key` to search for the entry not `ep2.data`. So update your code to

```
//--v
ep2.key = (void *) "cpe1";
ep_ptr = hsearch(ep2, FIND);
```

As you have not set `ep2.key` the `hsearch()` function tries to access uninitialized pointer causing segmentation fault.

Comment: No, it's not wrong. If you examine how `hsearch` works, you'll see you only need to set `key` for the `FIND` variant, and that _is_ being set here.

Comment: HOw can i look at the implementation of hsearch?

Comment: @Abhishek, I guess its opensource so you can find its source code using google.

Comment: @Rohan i tried and couldnt find the source code and hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
ep2.data = (void *) "cpe1";
ep_ptr = hsearch(ep2, FIND);
```

That first statement there is in error, you need to set the *key* to what you want to find, not the *data.*

Because you haven't set the key to anything, it has some arbitrary value in it (it's not static storage duration, so it's not initialised).

Then, `hsearch` is then running string functions on it (such as `strlen`) which is why you're getting the crash:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    __strlen_sse2 () at ...
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    (running string function on non-string).
```

Your code should instead be:

```
ep2.key = (void *) "cpe1";
ep_ptr = hsearch(ep2, FIND);
```

Comment: It will also crash because both the key and the data inside ep2 are uninitialized pointers.

Comment: @Gull, you only need to set the key for find. The return value is then the address of the hash entry containing both. And the data _was_ initialised, it's just that it should have been the key.

Answer (score 0):

In last printf, ep2.key which is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

i notice a few things.

1. You are allocating `ptr` repeatedly within the loop but you are not freeing it. So thats a memory leak right there.
2. What is the data type for `ep.data`? Why do you have to convert to `(void *)`? Then again you are converting it to `(char *)`!!. Why?? If you `data` is already of `char` type then why this need to convert to `(void *)` repeatedly?

Fix these errors and then give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

That line does not look correct:
`ep2.data = (void *) "cpe1";`

I found the definition of ENTRY so you'll have a better view of why it does not work as expected:
`typedef struct entry {
               char *key;
               void *data;
           } ENTRY;`
You need to first allocate both key and data before copying all the bytes in it.

Comment: For hsearch(), only the key member needs to be set. `ep2.data = (void *) "cpe1";` is perfectly fine to initialize ep2.data, there's no bytes to copy in. However the error is that it should be `key`, not `data` that's initialized: `ep2.key = (void *) "cpe1";`